# kustomize and kubectl not finding CRDs

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I'm using kustomize to pipe a manifest to kubectl on a new k8s cluster (v1.17.2). This includes CRDs, but other objects are unable to find them. For example:

```
unable to recognize "STDIN": no matches for kind "Certificate" in version "cert-manager.io/v1alpha2"
unable to recognize "STDIN": no matches for kind "IngressRoute" in version "traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1"
```

The CRDs are defined in the `resources` section of my kubectl, they show in the output which I'm piping to kubectl, and I'm sure this approach of putting everything in one file worked last time I did it.

If I apply the CRDs first, then apply the main manifest separately, it all goes through without a problem. Can I do them all at the same time? If so, what am I doing wrong; if not, why did it work before?

Can anyone point me at where the problem may lie?

Sample CRD definition:

```
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: ingressroutetcps.traefik.containo.us
spec:
  group: traefik.containo.us
  names:
    kind: IngressRouteTCP
    plural: ingressroutetcps
    singular: ingressroutetcp
  scope: Namespaced
  version: v1alpha1
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across your question when working on an issue with trying to bring up Traefik with Kustomize on Kubernetes... My issue was resolved by ensuring the namespace was accurate in my kustomization.yml file. In my case, I had to change it to match what was in the other yml files in my deployment. Not sure if you eventually figured it out but I figured I would respond in case that was it...

Comment: Hey, I did a bit more testing and it required setting the namespace as default throughout for it to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Kustomize does not, yet, have a way to control order of object creation. If you are piping straight into kubectl then you have to either separate the CRDs into their own app so that you apply CRDs, wait for them to finished and then apply the resources that depend on them. Or you run the apply twice.

When using kustomize with a GitOps tools they tend to have a custom way of setting resource ordering creation. Such as [sync-waves for Argo-CD](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/sync-waves/) or [kustomization depends-on in Flux](https://github.com/fluxcd/kustomize-controller#control-the-execution-order).

Answer (score 0):

i met the same issue, i guess it is about that `kubetcl` could not find the resource if trying to install the `crd` on the cluster first, to verify this, could running the command `kubectl api-resources`, new `crd` will not in the list, but if you `apply` the `crd` first, then  the `crd` record will be there, then `kustomize build . | kubectl apply -f -` can works fine. But i really do not know how to  add the resource firstly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using `Skaffold` and deploying all my `CRDs` with `kubectl`:

```yaml
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests: 
    - custom_resources.yaml
  kustomize:
    paths:
    - kustomize_directory
```